# Find if an interval/range is a part of a longer interval/range efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a sorted numpy 2d array `x` with a combination of start and end positions of two intervals in each row:

```
[[x_start_1, x_end_1, y_start_1, y_end_1],
 [x_start_2, x_end_2, y_start_2, y_end_2],
 ...
 [x_start_n, x_end_n, y_start_n, y_end_n]]
```

The array is ordered descending by the length between `x_start_n` and `x_end_n`. The length of `x` and `y` intervals from the same row is always the same.

The question is: What would be the most efficient and nicest solution to find if `x` and `y` intervals in a given row are sub-intervals of any `x` and `y` intervals from any of the rows above?

Example:

```
array([[35, 39,  1,  5],
       [20, 24,  4,  8],
       [32, 36, 10, 14],
       [35, 38,  1,  4], --> TRUE
       [35, 38, 21, 24],
       [19, 22,  2,  5],
       [36, 39,  2,  5], --> TRUE
       [20, 23,  4,  7], --> TRUE
       [      ...     ]])
```

The only solution I can think of and I implemented is doing a double for loop and extending a list of valid rows and using it in the next iteration for the comparison.

For easier visualization:

```
1.      ---------    |         ---------
2.    -----          |           -----
3.        ---        |            ---          -> TRUE
4.             --    |                --       -> TRUE
```

Thanks for your help! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a vectorized way leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
m1 = x[:,0,None]<=x[:,0]
m2 = x[:,1,None]>=x[:,1]

m3 = x[:,2,None]<=x[:,2]
m4 = x[:,3,None]>=x[:,3]

m12 = m1 & m2
m34 = m3 & m4
out = np.triu((m12 & m34),1).any(0)
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [2]: x
Out[2]: 
array([[35, 39,  1,  5],
       [20, 24,  4,  8],
       [32, 36, 10, 14],
       [35, 38,  1,  4],
       [35, 38, 21, 24],
       [19, 22,  2,  5],
       [36, 39,  2,  5],
       [20, 23,  4,  7]])

In [3]: out
Out[3]: array([False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True])
```